# How to create a "complex" header in HTML?

Tags: html, css, header

I wanted to create an header in HTML but I made some mistakes and can't figure out how i do it the right way.

This is how I have tried to do it:

```css
    .xyz-logo {
    float:left;
    width:472px;
    
    }

    .headerlayout h1{
    position:center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    font-size: x-large;
    width:1920px;
    height:200px;
    background:lightgrey;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="headerlayout"> 
         <img class="xyz-logo" src="C:\Users\..."  alt="Logo">   
         <h1 >This is the title</h1>               
      </div>
```

This is a picture of how it should look:

[image]

Comment: You can use css `grid` or `flex` to achieve the kind of header. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: There is no such thing as position center

Comment: why is there no dynamic field tag in your example? and if there is a picture, then provide a dynamic link to the picture

Answer (score -1):

As Paul mentioned, you could use Flexbox or Grid to solve it, but if you want something simple that you can play with, here is a solution using absolute positioning.
just change the top, left, and bottom values to change its positioning. The transform in the title is so it is always centered.

```css
  .headerlayout{
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightgrey;
      height: 200px;
    }
    
    .xyz-logo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .headerlayout h1{
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 35px;
      
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    }
    
    .something{
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0%;
      left:0%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="headerlayout"> 
      <img class="xyz-logo" src="C:\Users\..."  alt="Logo">   
      <h1>This is the title</h1>    
      <div class="something">Something that changes</div>
  </div >
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/0k6vo8d9/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the Grid Layout that Paul mentioned, but it was a little  to much for me.